# How does DataTables output a table with server side processing?

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I am using DataTables server side (https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/) to create a paginated table from a MySQL table.

I have created a simple table using DataTables: http://clients.serallo.co.uk/formtest/

I would like to work out how DataTables generates the table, as I cannot seem to find any occurrence of `<td>` in the script.

DataTables currently outputs something similar to this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
        <td class="sorting_1">[mysql result]</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to be able to add extra code alongside the MySQL output. For example, to turn the output into a hyperlink:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
        <td class="sorting_1"><a href="[mysql result]">[mysql result]</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I cannot do this as I cannot work out where DataTables is outputting the HTML code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [render](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) for this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "pull_2.php",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return "<a href=" + full[0] + ">" + full[0] +"</a>"; }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this example let's say you are returning a dataset with 1 column of data.  Within `render`, you build the hyperlink with html and an indexed reference to the row of data.  `full` represents the entire row.

If you were returning multiple columns, you could build the hyperlink with different fields, e.g. an Id for the hyperlink, and a string for the link text.

Comment: That was the gap that I was missing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you are putting in td

Just add these classes and `<thead>` tag, it works

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" id="data_show">

<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>

$('#data_show').DataTable();
```

Comment: Sorry, this was not what I meant. I think I didn't phrase the question very well.

I have rewrote the question.

Comment: so, for every td you need to add <a href="[mysql result]">, it's simple just add it in td.

Comment: But I cannot see where DataTables creates the <td>, that is the problem.